# JQuery to Reset all the indexes after dynamically add or remove rows

Tags: jquery

I am dynamically adding or removing div elements. My sample html would look like:

```
<!-- 1st dynamic block -->
<div class="container-fluid well dynamic-wrap">
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>LAN</strong></td>
            <td><input id="lan-1" name="details[0].lan" value="1" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!-- 2nd dynamic block -->
<div class="container-fluid well dynamic-wrap">
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>LAN</strong></td>
            <td><input id="lan-1" name="details[0].lan" value="1" type="text"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Here, I have added 2nd dynamic block using jquery clone. 
Now on click of 'Next' button I need to reset the name attribute index before submitting the page.
So, for 1st and 2nd block name attributes will become
    name="details[0].lan"
    name="details[1].lan"

Please provide some solution how to do this in JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to re-sync the names just do the following.  Keep in mind you should re-sync the id's as well as id's should be unique.

```
$('div table :text').each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr({
        'id': 'lan-' + (i+1).toString(),
        'name': 'details[' + i + '].lan'
    });
});
```

**Updated Code**

This will allow you to update everything regardless of the names.

```
$('div table :text').each(function(i) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var name = $(this).attr('name');

    id = id.replace(/-\d+/g, '-' + (i+1));
    name = name.replace(/\[\d+\]/g, '[' + i + ']');
    $(this).attr({
        'id': id,
        'name': name
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dklingman/baURf/

Comment: I just noticed that there is also _removing_ involved so this is better ;)

Comment: Actually what I am looking for is 1) iterate through divs with class 'dynamic-wrap' and then for each instance of iteration again iterate through the input elements and reset the indexes. Any solution for this apporach. So, you can consider there is a div wrapping both the blocks (1st and 2nd dyanamically added)

Comment: I do something very similar for a project I'm currently working on where rows are added and removed dynamically.  The difference is that when I do a remove before I do the remove I get the index value of the row to be removed.  Now I just only need to start at that index position and loop to the end of the list of elements.  So if you tweak and combine both mine answer and @BatuZet answer it would be a bit more efficient.

Comment: Got your approach. But in my current project, user can remove any of the already added rows (from any position), so I though of just resetting all the index before submitting the page. Any help on this apporach.

Comment: I tried doing this...but its not working: x = 0;
 $('.dynamic-wrap').each(function(i, dynamicObj) {
  alert("dynamic called=>"+dynamicObj);
  $($dynamicObj).find(':input').each(function(j, obj) {
   if(obj.name != 'transactionGrid_wf'){
    var objNameFirst = obj.name.substring(0, obj.name.indexOf("["));
    var objNameLast  = obj.name.substring(obj.name.lastIndexOf("]")+1, obj.name.length);
    if ($(obj).hasClass("gridRowNum")) {
     // empty
    } else {
     obj.name = objNameFirst + "[" + i +"]" + objNameLast;
     //alert(obj.name);
    }
   }
  });
  x++;
 }

Comment: details[0].lan is just a sample in the above html . I will have many fields like details[0].lan, details[0].ipAddr, details[0].moip, etc

Comment: @Sameer you can add as many fields as you wish, by modificating this `$(value).attr('name','details['+index+'].lan').prop('id','lan-'+index+'');` for ex. `$(value).attr('name','details['+index+'].ipAddr').prop('id','ipAddr-'+index+'');`

Answer (score 1):

I added two new rows, and a button 'ADD', plus deleting the row (I just copied your html)

```
<!-- 1st dynamic block -->
<div class="container-fluid well dynamic-wrap">
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>LAN</strong></td>
            <td><input id="lan-1" name="details[0].lan" value="1" type="text"></td>
                <td class="remove">X</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!-- 2nd dynamic block -->
<div class="container-fluid well dynamic-wrap">
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>LAN</strong></td>
            <td><input id="lan-1" name="details[0].lan" value="1" type="text"></td>
                 <td class="remove">X</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
    <div class="container-fluid well dynamic-wrap">
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>LAN</strong></td>
            <td><input id="lan-1" name="details[0].lan" value="1" type="text"></td>
                 <td class="remove">X</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
        <div class="container-fluid well dynamic-wrap">
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>LAN</strong></td>
            <td><input id="lan-1" name="details[0].lan" value="1" type="text"></td>
                 <td class="remove">X</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
    <input type="button" id="add" name="add" value="ADD">
```

After adding, and deleting the function resets the row, so before the submit you will send reseted/newly ordered values

```
var input = $('.dynamic-wrap input').attr('name','details');

    function resetTheOrder(){
    $.each(input,function(index,value){
        $(value).attr('name','details['+index+'].lan').prop('id','lan-'+index+'');
     });
    }

$('#add').on('click',function(){
// after adding new row
    resetTheOrder();
});

$('.remove').on('click',function(){
// after deleting new row
    resetTheOrder();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this after cloning and adding the table

```
var last_tbl = $(".table-condensed:last");
var last_index = $(".table-condensed").length;
last_tbl.find("input").attr("id","lan-" + last_index).attr("name","details["+ (last_index - 1) +"].lan");
```

Answer (score 0):

After cloning you should try this

```
var input = $('.dynamic-wrap input').attr('name','details');
$.each(input,function(index,value){
    $(value).attr('name','details['+index+'].lan').prop('id','lan-'+index+'');
});
```

Update:

```
    var input = $('.dynamic-wrap input').attr('name','details');

    function resetTheOrder(){
    $.each(input,function(index,value){
        $(value).attr('name','details['+index+'].lan').prop('id','lan-'+index+'');
     });
    }
```

Call `resetTheOrder()` function after adding some new div, or deleting this will recount the order..

Comment: I need to perform reset operation not after cloning. But when the user clicks submit/next button. User is free to add/remove many div content.

Comment: Any solution where I can reset indexes when page is submitted. and also I will have few more elements on the page along with "lan". I am trying this approach, but its not working. What could be error here.

Comment: $('.dynamic-wrap').each(function(i, dynamicObj) {
  alert("dynamic called=>"+dynamicObj);
  $($dynamicObj).find(':input').each(function(j, obj) {
   alert("obj.name=>");
   if(obj.name != 'transactionGrid_wf'){
    var objNameFirst = obj.name.substring(0, obj.name.indexOf("["));
    var objNameLast  = obj.name.substring(obj.name.lastIndexOf("]")+1, obj.name.length);
    if ($(obj).hasClass("gridRowNum")) {
     // empty
    } else {
     obj.name = objNameFirst + "[" + i +"]" + objNameLast;
     //alert(obj.name);
    }
   }
  });
  x++;

Comment: Then, please edit your question with more code and description of your question, hard to find out what you want to achive.